# Selenium IDE - record right click

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Im using Selenium IDE for record test for my web app.

**Selenium IDE do not recognize the right click in my div**. I've customized right click over my div and I wanna test relative functions.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Tommaso

Answer (score 6):

Use 'contextMenu' / 'contextMenuAt' to do a right-click.
But as far as i know, you can not record that yet, so you have to add it manually.

Comment: After using the contextMenu i have no error in my log but it is not executing in my web page? so how to have that right click in my page?