# How to clickRight in selenium dont use javascript and fireevent?

Tags: javascript, selenium, contextmenu, seam, right-click

I have one contextmenu and i want to clickRight in selenium test. i try to use
fireEvent but i m failed. and i dont know java script. So how to do clikright in selenium.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use selenium.contextMenu(locator)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the recording feature of the ide? What code does it produce?

Search the forum and you find:
[Selenium IDE - record right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172955/selenium-ide-record-right-click)

Comment: I want to use like selenium.click("elementXpath"); or selenium.rightClick(""); but i cant do this.