# How To Automate "Right click" event in Selenium IDE and opening the link in New window/tab

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, right-click

I am using Selenium IDE for a google search scenario.

```
1 open google

2 then  type "india" and click on the search button

3 then go to any link and right clicking on that link 
  and open that link in new tab or window
```

what i have done till now is

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>india</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=gbqfb</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>contextMenu</td>
    <td>//*[@id='rso']/li[3]/div/h3/a</td>
    <td> </td>
</tr>
```

What i am not able to do is :  **right click on the link and then open that link in new window.**

can anyone please suggest what need to do .

Answer (score 0):

"right click on the link and then open that link in new window" this is the browser feature not the page feature.. that why you not able to record it in IDE.

If you wanna know about recording right click, try click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172955/selenium-ide-record-right-click)

Comment: i have used "contextMenu" command but after that how i will open that link in new window or tab ? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can Press Ctrl key and click on the link so that it gets opened in a new tab.

For using control key in Selenium IDE use the below keywords.

```
controlKeyDown ( ) 

//code for clicking the link

controlKeyUp ( )
```

Comment: i have used  the below code 

`code`
<tr>
 <td>controlKeyDown</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//*[@id='rso']/li[3]/div/h3/a</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>controlKeyUp</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

`code`
its not working

Comment: at which step it is getting failed? Can you post the error message if any?

Comment: in the log no error is showing  but the right click and and then open link in new tab functionality is not happening

Answer (score 0):

you can **get the href attribute of that link and then open it in a new window by using openWindow() command**.

Comment: can u please tell me where i have to use the openwindow command , my code is given in the question

Answer (score 0):

Following opens the URL in a new tab, if you've configured Firefox to open new tabs instead of new windows.

```
storeAttribute | link-locator-here | myURLvariableName |
getEval | window.open( storedVars.myURLvariableName, '_blank' /* or tab target name*/ ); |
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple of days for research, I finally found the way to **simulate Right-click in Selenium IDE** through the `execute script` command:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('CSS_SELECTOR_GOES_HERE');

const eventContextMenu = new MouseEvent('contextmenu', {
    bubbles: true,
});

el.dispatchEvent(eventContextMenu);
```

**The trick here is that `bubbles: true` is required param.**

P.S: [Link to original answer in GitHub thread](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/754#issuecomment-688308753).

[image]