# "Right Click" in Selenium IDE to bring up the Context Menu

Tags: contextmenu, selenium-ide, right-click, save-as

How can you bring up the context menu (as if you were right clicking on an element on a page) so you can see the context menu in the browser?

I see the contextMenu and contextMenuAt commands are available, but they always seem to pass the "T" flag so that the link opens in a new tab.  I don't want that.  I want the menu to come up so I can simulate a 'k' keypress and have the file download to my desktop.

How do you pass a switch/param to contextMenu and/or contextMenuAt so that you can actually do more than just open whatever in a new tab?

Comment: Please refer to the original response here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63788239/4591347 Thank you.